# Scala best practices for mocking lazy vals

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I am new to Scala and am working with a large code base. There is a trait with a lazy val, and I want to unit-test one of the classes implementing that trait. For my unit tests I want to mock the lazy val.

My Java sensibilities tell me that I need to rewrite the trait so that it is more testable

Now to my actual question: Someone (with more Scala experience) suggested to me that I shouldn't refactor the production code. Instead it was suggested to me that in each unit test I should create an anonymous class of the class I want to test. In the anonymous class I can override the lazy val.  Apparently this anonymous class testing is already being done elsewhere in the code base. But this seems like extremely bad practise to me. Am I wrong? Is this a standard practise for Scala developers?

I am very interested in hearing reasons 'why' this is a good or bad idea

Comment: This is opinion-based and therefore off-topic. But _in my opinion_, you _absolutely should_ refactor production code to be testable (and to otherwise improve it). Having to subclass the test subject in order to test is a code smell and an anti-pattern in general. I agree with you that it is a really bad practice. Let the holy war begin!

Comment: I would guess the only reason that developer said that is because the redactor would be very big _(whenever or not that is a valid reason is open to debate)_. In general `val` in traits are a bad idea unless you need dependent types, and the fact it is `lazy` means that they already had problems with the initialization order of that variable which means the code has already gave them problems and signals that, as you say, the code is not really well designed.

Comment: @Dima Thank you. Can I ask if you can direct me to some resource (blog post, book, article, whatever) which could explain why (in the writer's opinion) subclassing the test subject is a code smell or anti-pattern. I already believe it is bad, but my problem is that I can't justify why it is bad

Comment: Well, I don't know about blog posts, but I think it's obvious that subclassing for testing is bad because you end up testing a different class from what you run in production.

Comment: I thought it was obvious too lol